# Flutter Web - space bar not working in release mode

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I'm facing a big problem in flutter, when using a release mode of web version of the app.
In the textformfield is not working when we hit the space bar. If you press twice, a "." appears in the input. It's very strange. The TextFormField is not inside any scroll controller. I saw a solution here that we have to put `LogicalKeySet(LogicalKeyboardKey.space): ActivateIntent()` in the MaterialApp call.

It solves the space bar problem in the TextFormField, but creates another: the tab button doesn`t work anymore to change the field inside the form, it goes to the browser buttons. Can somebody help me?